# OracleConnection life cycle

Tags: c#, database-connection, odp

I'm using `ODP` on my DB application. I created wrapper classes over `ODP` for my application. It's a desktop applicaton it runs in a linear way(user can not do any other operation during a running operation. GUI is locked during operations). Considering this i created a single `OracleConnection` object as a member and using it for all queries. But as i see best practice is using sth. like:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))  
{  
    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();  

    command.CommandText = "mysp_GetValue";  
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  

    connection.Open();  
    object ret = command.ExecuteScalar();  
}
```

in all cases(even in linear execution).

Do i have to use like this or is single `OracleConnection` enough?

Now i'm calling the connect of my wrapper object and it calls `m_OracleConnection.open(connectionString)` while application is starting. But if i create a separate connection for every query how will i hold the state of the connection? Will a boolean value like `bool m_IsConnected` be enough?

And how can i warn the user if connection is lost soft or hard way?

Comment: I don't understand your question clearly but be aware of `OracleConnection` API is [obsolete now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.aspx)

Comment: It's not `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection` under `ADO.NET`, it's `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection` under `ODP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important question under this is: does the ODP `OracleConnection` implement connection-pooling? If it *does* (and many ADO.NET providers *do*), then the "best practice" code is *absolutely fine*; it might *look* like you are opening a connection, but with connection pooling that `Open()` is actually "get an underlying connection from the pool, or connect if there isn't one available". The `Dispose()` (at the end of `using`) releases the underlying connection back to the pool. With this approach, then, there is *no need* to track the state of the connection - you let the pool worry about that.

It looks like connection pooling is enabled in ODP by default, with connection-string parameters to tweak it ([source](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ramamohang/OracleDataProviderfor.NET212012005015557AM/OracleDataProviderfor.NET2.aspx))

Comment: I understand. And i guess i only have to worry about the state if there is a hard or soft problem with conenction. In case of a connection i can show a message box to user indicating the problem? And registering to `StateChange` event of `OracleConnection` will be useless because there will be a separate `OracleConnection` for each operation?

Comment: @gesus on the message box: whatever you choose, I guess. On the `StateChange` - yes, for *that* to work you'd need to keep the connection instance open and available